# Run ssh on Apache -> Failed to get a pseudo terminal: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, flask, apache2.2

I'm using flask with apache(mod_wsgi).

When I use ssh module with external command `subprocess.call("ssh ......",shell=True)`

(My Python Flask code : Not wrong)

`ssh = "sshpass -p \""+password+"\" ssh -p 6001 "+username+"@"+servername+" \"mkdir ~/MY_SERVER\""`

`subprocess.call(ssh, shell=True)`

I got this error on Apache error_log :  `Failed to get a pseudo terminal: Permission denied`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem under RHEL 7. It's due to SELinux blocking apache user to access pty. To solve:

1. Disable or set SELinux as permissive (check your security needs): edit /etc/selinux/config and reboot.
2. Allow apache to control its directory for storing SSH keys:

   sudo -u apache

   chown apache /etc/share/httpd

   ssh to desired host, accept key.

Answer (score 0):

I think apache's login shell is "/sbin/nologin".

If you want to allow apache to use shell command, modify /etc/passwd and change the login shell to another shell like "/bin/bash".

However, this method is vulnerable to security. Many python ssh modules are available in internet. Use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems frightfully insecure.  If you cannot use a Python library for your SSH connections, then you should at least plug the hole that is `shell=True`.  There is very little here which is done by the shell anyway; doing it in Python affords you more control, and removes a big number of moving parts.

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sshpass', '-p', password,
    '/usr/bin/ssh', '-T', '-p', '6001', '{0}@{1}'.format(username, servername),
    'mkdir ~/MY_SERVER'])
```

If you cannot hard-code the paths to `sshpass` and `ssh`, you should at least make sure you have a limited, controlled `PATH` variable in your environment before doing any of this.

The fix for `Failed to get a pseudo-terminal` is usually to add a `-T` flag to the `ssh` command line.  I did that above.  If your real code actually requires a tty (which `mkdir` obviously does not), perhaps experiment with `-t` instead, and/or redirecting standard input and standard output.